# Grafana and influxdb - draw all series from the database

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have some data from different sensors that can be plugged in and out, each sensor has unique ID.

Is there any way to draw **all** the time series for all the sensors in the Grafana database? I don't want to enumerate 50+ sensors, especially considering the fact that they can come and go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not enough details on measurements and tags in your database and how you want to draw time series: all in one graph or one per graph.

I assume you have sensorID as tag in measurement.

For one sensor per graph solution may look like this:

1. Create template variable `sensorID` and fill it from query

   `SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "yourMeas" WITH key="sensorID"`
2. Create `Graph panel` on dashboard with metrics query using template variable. Smth like:

   `SELECT mean(value) FROM "yourMeas" WHERE "sensorID" =~ /$sensorID$/ AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time(5m) fill(null)`
3. Select `sensorID` template variable name in `Repeat panel` 'General' graph edit tab to repeat graph for all values of your $sensorID template variable. Alternatively you can set `Repeat for` in row options settings to repeat rows instead of graph panels.

For all sensors in one graph you don't need all these 'repeat for' - it's enough to add `sensorID` tag to GROUP BY in query:

`SELECT mean(value) FROM "yourMeas" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(5m), "sensorID" fill(null)`

and use tag value in alias: for example set `ALIAS BY` to $tag_sensorID